# Trouble getting UITextField [textField frame];

Tags: objective-c, ios

Current Code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"begin edit: %@", textField);
}
```

Related output:

```
2011-10-30 09:12:08.436 My Project[83470:207] begin edit: <UITextField: 0x6c349d0; frame = (112 2; 182 39); text = 'My Name'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c34af0>>
```

So I know the textfield frame is there, but when I try to grab it:

code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"begin edit: %@", [textField frame]);
    // also tried textField.frame -- same thing
}
```

error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCES (code=1, address=0x42e00000)
```

output:

```
(lldb)
```

I've been spinning my wheels on this and I'm not sure where to go next. Thanks for reading my question.

** EDIT - cell xib instantiation (where the textfield lives) **

*note:* the textfield comes from a xib file that is just a table cell.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ValidatedTextViewTableCell";

ValidatedTextViewTableCell *cell = (ValidatedTextViewTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ValidatedTextViewTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = validatedTextViewTableCell;
    self.validatedTextViewTableCell = nil;
}
```

Comment: I think you should post the rest of your code as there are no errors in the code that you have posted. Also, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is usually due to a memory management issue, so we need to so how you are instantiating the textfield variable.

Comment: @XcodeDev I added some more info about where the textfield comes from. Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work:

```
NSLog(@"begin edit: %@", [textField frame]);
```

Because `frame` is a CGRect type, not an object, so the `%@` format specifier, which is for objects only, blows up when handed it. You'll need to log the frame by each of its components, like this:

```
NSLog(@"begin edit: %f, %f, %fx%f", [textField frame].origin.x [textField frame].origin.y, [textField frame].size.width, [textField frame].size.height);
```

Comment: Instead of writing that annoying format string you can do it like this - `NSLog(@"begin edit: %@", NSStringFromCGRect([textField frame]));`.